# Pass a variable value from Base Adapter to activity

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have a set a variable in my Base Adapter class, now I want to get(pass) this variable in my related Activity. I am not getting how to do this.

Here is my code.

```
  public class TourDescAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Descriptions> descriptList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ViewHolder holder;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private OnClickListener clickListener; 
    Activity context;
    //TourDescription tourDesc;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> obj = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> discountedTourDetails = null;
    String price = null, prodId = null;
    String promoTourname, tourName;

    public TourDescAdapter(List<Descriptions> descriptList,
            TourDescription activity) {
        this.context = activity;
        this.descriptList = descriptList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        clickListener = (OnClickListener) activity;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return this.descriptList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return this.descriptList.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tourlist, null);

            /****
             * Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
             * views we want to bind data to
             ****/
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rlayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tourlayout);

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tourtitletext);
            holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tourdes);
            holder.amountButton = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.amtBtn);
            holder.pinButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pinBtn);
            holder.arrowButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowBtn);
            holder.serialText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pinText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText((String) descriptList.get(position)
                .getImageTitle());
        holder.desc.setText((String) descriptList.get(position)
                .getImageDescription());
        ((ImageView) holder.rlayout.getChildAt(0)).setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                .decodeFile((RaconTours.PATH + RaconTours.city + File.separator
                        + TourDescription.currentTour.getObjtourName()
                        + File.separator + descriptList.get(position)
                        .getImagePath().split("/")[2]).replace(" ", "_")));

        if (position == 0) {
            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("downloadDetails", 0);
            String isTourDownloaded = settings.getString(TourDescription.currentTour.getObjtourName(), "");
            if (isTourDownloaded.equals("true")) {
            //if (!(TourDescription.downloadFile.exists())||TourDescription.downloadFile.exists() == false ) {
            //if (TourDescription.currentTour.getIsTourDownloaded() == true) {
                //holder.pinButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //holder.arrowButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //holder.serialText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                holder.amountButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.amountButton.setText("Start");



            } else {
                File promoPlistPath = new File(RaconTours.PATH + "promocode.txt");
                checkPromoCode(promoPlistPath);
                if (discountedTourDetails != null) {
                    tourName = (String) discountedTourDetails.get("promoTour");
                    price = (String) discountedTourDetails.get("discountPrice");
                    prodId = (String) discountedTourDetails.get("disProId");

                    holder.amountButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // Setting the background color
                    holder.title
                            .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#993333"));
                    // Setting the Title color
                    holder.title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    // Centering the title
                    holder.title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    // setting the city
                    ((TextView) holder.rlayout.getChildAt(1))
                            .setText(RaconTours.city);
                    ((TextView) holder.rlayout.getChildAt(1))
                            .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // setting the Tour Amount
                    holder.amountButton.setText("$" +price);
                    //promoPlistPath.delete();
                } else {

                    // Enabling the two buttons
                    holder.amountButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // Setting the background color
                    holder.title
                            .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#993333"));
                    // Setting the Title color
                    holder.title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    // Centering the title
                    holder.title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    // setting the city
                    ((TextView) holder.rlayout.getChildAt(1))
                            .setText(RaconTours.city);
                    ((TextView) holder.rlayout.getChildAt(1))
                            .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // setting the Tour Amount
                    holder.amountButton.setText(TourDescription.currentTour
                            .getObjPrice());

                }
            }
        } else {
            holder.amountButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.pinButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.arrowButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.serialText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.title.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            ((TextView) holder.rlayout.getChildAt(1))
                    .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void checkPromoCode(File promoPlistPath) {
        if (promoPlistPath.exists()) {
            try {

                ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(promoPlistPath));
                obj = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) inStream
                        .readObject();
                for (HashMap<String, Object> tmpObj : obj) {
                    promoTourname = (String) tmpObj.get("promoTour");
                    if (promoTourname.equals(TourDescription.currentTour.getObjtourName())) {
                        discountedTourDetails = tmpObj;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        Button pinButton;
        Button amountButton;
        RelativeLayout rlayout;
        TextView title;
        TextView desc;
        Button arrowButton;
        EditText serialText;

    }
}
```

Here

```
    prodId = (String) discountedTourDetails.get("disProId");
```

I want to pass prodId to related activity.

Note: Base Adapter is called from the activity

```
    adapter = new TourDescAdapter(currentTour.getListOfDescriptions(), this);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Any one can tell me how to do this?

Comment: create a public method in adapter with return variable value, and access this method from activity like variable=adapter.methodName();

Comment: @tejas i got the same issue ! how could i pass the value from baseadapter to activity

Comment: Hi priya, sorry for the delayed response. I was not available online these days, can you tell me what exactly is your scenario?

Comment: You can either create a shared preference there or if you want something to be done after button click, then let your activity implement OnClickListenerand then in the adapter class constructor, assign this to activity object like this clickListener = (OnClickListener) orderlistObj; Then for the button in the getView method, holder.yourButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);Finally identify this button in your activity onclick method and get the data. Hope you are able to understand what I said :P Any doubts let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just use `String iGotTheString = adapter.prodId`?

Comment: I solved the problem, it may not be a standard way, but my intention was to fix this. I am calling this inside the constructor checkPromoCode(promoPlistPath);
  if (discountedTourDetails != null) {
   prodId = (String) discountedTourDetails.get("disProId");

  }