# Check box not getting checked after clicking listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have an activity where there is a list view having text view and a check box on the right. i want checkbox to be checked when the listview item is clicked. (Not on the checkbox). Like the one where android uses to check messages one by one to be deleted.

Can anyone help me in resolving this? I switched off

```
android:focusable="false
```

and

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

on checkbox.

Below is my list view item xml.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="1."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

And this is my code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(checkbox.isChecked())
            checkbox.setChecked(false);

        else
            checkbox.setChecked(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post some code (XML layout).

Comment: Please post/share code(xml of list item)!

Comment: Consider using a [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) (like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked`) or writing a custom checkable layout.

Comment: Specify this attribute to your main RelativeLayout     **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**

Comment: here where is your listview ?

Comment: http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: Guys i cracked it out. I used CheckedTextView as suggested by Sam and its working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:clickable="false"` to the CheckBox.

In your situation, it's better to use a CheckedTextView instead, and use `ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` to enable multi select.

`AbsoluteSizeSpan/RelativeSizeSpan + SpannableStringBuilder` could help you implement different text size in one TextView.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is too late but it works perfectly.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
              TextView tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              cb.performClick(); //this will trigger the checkbox
              //do here 
              if(checkbox.isChecked())
                  checkbox.setChecked(false);
              else
                  checkbox.setChecked(true);
        }
});
```

And if u want get the variable value from BaseAdapter for getting checked position or value etc check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845587/pass-a-variable-value-from-base-adapter-to-activity?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the xml that i modified to add CheckedtextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <CheckedTextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:paddingRight="6dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the onClick method written inside getView on listAdapter

```
CheckedTextView chkBox = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.CheckedTextView01);
        chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ((CheckedTextView) v).toggle();
            }
        });
```